# Using DialogFragment as one of the Fragment in Android NavController

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have a graph defined using XML and I added a DialogFragment as one of the Fragment in my NavGraph. when I call NavController.navigate with resId and bundle on that nav controller I don't see any Dialog being displayed. Is there any way I can use DialogFragment instead of standard Fragment?

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/noLoginDialog"
        android:name="com.ram.view.NoLoginDialog"
        android:label="NoLoginDialog">
        <argument
            android:name="argTitle"
            android:defaultValue="null"
            app:type="string"/>
        <argument
            android:name="argBody"
            android:defaultValue="null"
            app:type="string"/>
        <argument
            android:name="argButton"
            android:defaultValue="null"
            app:type="string"/>
    </fragment>
```

and my action is defined as below

```
 <container_fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.ram.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_noAuthAlertDialog"
            app:destination="@id/noLoginDialog"/>
    </container_fragment>
```

My other actions with activity and fragments works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hum, Navigation Library will never open an Fragment as Dialog, it just replace the first (home destination) to other destination in your NavHostFragment.

Google said:

> A destination is any place you can navigate to in your app. While
>   destinations are usually Fragments representing specific screens..

Please provide more information, like your navigation code (java/kotlin).

Take a read on this official Google post to understand more about Navigation:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing

Comment: Navigation currently does not support Dialogs, I did discuss this with Ian Lake (Author of Navigation) at Android Dev Summit and he said they have a plan to support it in the future.

Comment: It does not make sense. Since navigation is to navigate away to somewhere in the app and I do not think that show a dialog can be considered "navigation"

Comment: DialogFragment is a subclass of Fragment and can be a valid navigation destination depends on how it is being used. There can be a full-screen dialog which can represent a destination.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call up DialogFragment from navigation, you will just have to explicitly tell the navigation that you are going to use **dialog**

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/simCancelFinish"
    android:name="mk.telekom.kiosk.ui.dialogs.SimCancelFinish"
    android:label="SimCancelFinish" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_simCancelFinish_to_stornoSimFragment"
        app:destination="@id/stornoSimFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/stornoSimFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</dialog>
```